# Import as statement working differently for different modules?

Tags: python, import

I am learning Python, and right now I am learning about the import statements in Python. I was testing out some code, and I came across something unusual. Here is the code I was testing.

```
from math import pow as power
import random as x

print(pow(2, 3))
print(power(2, 3))
print(x.randint(0, 5))
print(random.randint(0, 5))
```

I learned that in Python, you can reassign the names of modules using `as`, so I reassigned pow to power. I expected both `pow(2, 3)` and `power(2, 3)` to output the exact same stuff because all I did was change the name. However, `pow(2, 3)` outputs `8`, which is an integer, while `power(2, 3)` outputs `8.0`, which is a float. Why is that?

Furthermore, I imported the `random` module as well, and set its name to be `x`. In the case of the pow and power, both the old name, `pow`, and the new name, `power`, worked. But with this random module, only the new name, `x`, works, and the old name, `random`, doesn't work. `print(x.randint(0, 5))` works, but `random.randint(0, 5)` doesn't work. Why is this so?

Can anyone please explain to a Python newbie such as myself why my code is not working the way I expect it to? I am using Python version 3.62, if that helps.

Comment: Because `pow` is using the builtin `pow` function. When you use `as`, it will bind that function to that name. It will not import `math.pow` and bind it to the name `pow`, it will only import `math.pow` then bind it to a different name such as `power`.

Comment: Your expectation was wrong, when you use `as` it loads the module/function/class as another name. So `random` won't work. The reason that `pow` does, is because python has a built-in `pow` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because when you import `pow` from **math** as `power` and then you call `pow`, the `pow` you are calling is a **built-in** function, not the `pow` from the **math** module.

For `random` there is no built-in function in python so you only import the `x` one.

The pow built-in function [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow)

Comment: The most precise answer, double checked, you don't need to import math for pow() to work!

Comment: So are you are saying that the math module is a built-in function, while random is not built-in? Then how come I can use the random module if its not built-in? I'm not exactly understanding this. Also can you please explain clearly why `pow` returns an integer, while `power` reterns a float? I'm lost.

Comment: @parrot15 the `pow` function is the built-in. The *math* module has another `pow` function different from the built-in function, but as you renamed `math.pow` as *power* when you imported it, the `math.pow` function is not binded to `pow`. The thing is there are two different functions to use as `pow` the built-in and the one from **math**, as you are using different names, you have both working separately

Comment: @MartinAlonso Ok that makes perfect sense now. Upvoted and accepted. Thank you, cleared a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

when you use pow you are actually using the inbuilt pow function.

but there is no inbuilt function called random thus it does not work

normally in python if you use 'as' you can only use the module what you imported it as not what it was originally called